# Java Gate embedded

Tags: java, gate

I am trying to use Gate embedded to extract some entities.
I included the jar files from 
the bin and lib folder
this is the code:

```
    Out.prln("Initialising GATE...");
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("gate.home", "/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.2");
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            MainFrame.getInstance().setVisible(true);
            try {
                Factory.newDocument("This is a document");
            } catch (ResourceInstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
```

but I always get the following exception. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1287)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1348)
    at gate.Gate.main(Gate.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gate.Gate.getUserConfig()Lgate/util/OptionsMap;
    at gate.swing.XJFileChooser.getLocations(XJFileChooser.java:140)
    at gate.swing.XJFileChooser.<init>(XJFileChooser.java:70)
    at gate.gui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:493)
    at gate.gui.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:352)
    at gate.gui.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:348)
    at gate.Gate$1.run(Gate.java:27)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What is the name and package of your main class? Is it `gate.Gate` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because the class is in the classpath but its version doesn't match with your need. The class is found but you invoke a method which doesn't exist in the version of this class.

I think that you should use a more recent version of the GATE library.

For example this version    https://gate.ac.uk/releases/gate-3.1-build2270-ALL/doc/javadoc/ contains [the `gate.Gate`](https://gate.ac.uk/releases/gate-3.1-build2270-ALL/doc/javadoc/gate/Gate.html)  class providing the public method `OptionsMap getUserConfig()`.

Comment: Your first paragraph is correct, but I think the version of the GATE library is ok. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

When looking on the stack trace, I think your main class is named `gate.Gate` - the same name as the central class of the GATE library. And this conflict of names causes the problem.

Just rename your class or change its package and the error should be gone.